# How to make total price

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a variable of `personal` which has a value of 100000 and I have EditText and user need to input how much. Then I want to multiply `personal` with number in EditText.

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sukses_masuk);

        totalhargaa = findViewById(R.id.totalHarga);
        jadwal1 = findViewById(R.id.jadwal1);
        pertemuan1 = findViewById(R.id.pertemuan1);
        pertemuan2 = findViewById(R.id.pertemuan2);
        pertemuan3 = findViewById(R.id.pertemuan3);
        jadwalpilih = findViewById(R.id.jadwalpilih);
        jadwalpilih2 = findViewById(R.id.jadwalpilih2);
        jadwalpilih3 = findViewById(R.id.jadwalpilih3);
        jadwalpilih4 = findViewById(R.id.jadwalpilih4);
        pertemuan4 = findViewById(R.id.pertemuan4);
        jumlahpertemuan = findViewById(R.id.jumlahpertemuan);
        konfirmasiguru = findViewById(R.id.konfirmasiGuru);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.prosesorder);

        try {
            jumlahpertemuanholder = Integer.parseInt(jumlahpertemuan.getText().toString());
            keluarga = getIntent().getIntExtra("keluarga", 0);
            totalharga = keluarga * jumlahpertemuanholder;
            totalhargaa.setText(totalharga);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("DetailOrder", e + "");

        }
```

then this is my variable

```java
    LinearLayout pertemuan1, pertemuan2, pertemuan3, pertemuan4,jadwal1;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    Spinner tahun, bulan, minggu;
    EditText jumlahpertemuan;
    TextView jadwalpilih, jadwalpilih2, jadwalpilih3, jadwalpilih4, totalhargaa;
    String currentDateString, nama_guru, nama_santri;
    private Calendar date;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    String email;
    Button konfirmasiguru;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String personal, kelompok ;
    int jumlahpertemuanholder, keluarga, totalharga;
```

Comment: `onCreate`? So user hasn't had a chance to enter anything yet, right? I mean, you're in the process of creating the UI. So what value do you believe `jumlahpertemuan.getText().toString()` would return?

Comment: i am very new on android, i am still on senior high school and just started learning 2 month ago, yeah i know user hasn't had a change to enter, but i dont know how to make user can enter

Answer (score 1):

As @Andreas Pointed out executing this block of code in onCreate method is not a good idea. You Probably want to execute it on occurrence of an event (eg button click). apart from that your `totalharga` variable is an `int` and passing it directly to the `setText` method means that android would seek a resource with the corresponding `id` which is probably not what you meant. if you want to show the **int value** use it like this:

`totalhargaa.setText(String.valueOf(totalharga));`

Comment: well , i am very new on android studio, i just started 2 month, and so how do i do this? i want to multiply value user Input on EditText with Variable Personal which contain value of 1000, ex ( Edittext, user input 10 -> then 10 * 1000 ) so how do i do this

Comment: Your code is correct(except for setText method which i explained). You just have to place it on some event handlers to work without error. eg you can add and `onClickListener` to a button and place your `try...catch` block in `onClick` method.